# login form Error 500 after clicking on submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

login form Error 500 after clicking on submit
Hi everyone,
We have a group assignment in our php course and we are supposed to design a login system in PHP and MySQL. 
We wrote the form, the PHP script, created the database and everything is supposed to work except that when we enter the username and passwords specified on the database when you press the submit button, it brings us to a 500 internal error page.
The code is in a file called index.php in the /login folder and it should grant access to a file located in the parent folder.
Here is it:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();


// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location:../accessgranted.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "db.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";
$username_ph = "Enter Username";
$password_ph = "Enter password";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty quoted th trim function because it caused the same 500 error when trying to run the login page
    if(empty/*(trim*/($_POST["username"]/*)*/)){
        $username_err = "Entrez votre nom d'utilisateur";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty/*(trim*/($_POST["password"]/*)*/)){
        $password_err = "Entrez votre mot de passe";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM Users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){


                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);

                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){

                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: ../accessgranted.php");

                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }//added
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            } 
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($con);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <center> 
        <h1>Connection</h1>
        <h2>Login Assignment</h2>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <p align="left">Username</p>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" placeholder="<?= $username_ph?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <p align="left">Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<?= $password_ph?>" align="left">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>  </center>  
</body>
</html>
```

We have to hand it before Sunday so your help would be much appreciated

Comment: Check your error logs, if you don't have error logs, turn on error reporting. Depending on your settings, it may be because you're trying to `session_start()` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `error_reporting`, `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` settings in your `php.ini` file. They should be set to `E_ALL` and `"On"` respectively. You can also change these settings (except `display_startup_errors`) at the very beginning of your script to set them at runtime.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

After that, restart server.

And check the error causing in your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this led me to this trail: Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify()

Answer (score 0):

whenever you get 500 error that time you mistake on your syntax as you forgot to a comma, dot, brackets, SQL query many more